# What's the default traditional Chinese font?

Tags: 10.10, fonts

The only fonts that can render Chinese text are: WenQuanYi Micro Hei, WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono, Droid Sans (I think is unicode), FreeSans (I think is unicode too).

Changing Chinese text to Sans, FreeSans, Droid Sans render the same font). 
WenQuanYi Micro Hei, WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono render 'bolder' Chinese text.

EDIT: What I discovered so far:

Is not WenQuanYi Micro Hei, WenQuanYi Micro Hei, Droid Sans Fallback (Droid with CJK support).

It can only be FreeSans, or Deja vu Sans.

I'm not sure which one is being used as default one (clean installation)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

According to this ubuntuforums.org thread, [Deja vu Sans](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-801767.html) is the default chinese font.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the default font for Chinese characters is Un Botum, you can try it online here:

http://www.fonts2u.com/un-dotum.font

Unfortunately, being a Korean font, it's missing some fairly common characters for Chinese, such as 清.

Answer (score 0):

It is different per system. On my system is `Droid Sans Fallback`.

[Character Map](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CharacterMap) shows you per character which font is being used. Find your character in the list and right click on it. The character is shown larger and the actual font used is listed below.

[image: Right click on character in Character Map to see which font is used]